# limiting maximum number of messages sent by client to server

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I need to limit the connections that client can send in a specific time.My server accepts multiple requests from a client in single connection.

```
async def handle_client ( websocket, path):
    while 1:
        data =await websocket.recv( )

        #some long process here  1-2 seconds

        await websocket.send(result_from_long_process)

    return
        # One possibiliy is to find requests received from a
        # client per second  and if it is > threshold disconnect the client.
        # But how to find when the server got the specific request from client

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop( )
HOST = ''
PORT = 9116
server = websockets.serve(handle_client, HOST, PORT)
loop.run_until_complete(server)
loop.run_forever( )
```